# X64 ASP.net failing to find assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, 64-bit

I am having an issue with something that seems like it should be simple.  I am just trying to use the sharepoint object model from an ASP.net page.  It's running on Framework 3.5 (required by sharepoint), and I realize it needs to be set to build on x64 (also required by sharepoint from what I understand).  The issue is when I do this it returns "Could not load file or assemply ".  If I switch it to any CPU then it reports that the call to build SPSite can't find the site address.

Basically if I open a brand new web app project and switch it to framework 3.5 and build target x64 it will report this same error.  It seems like I am doing something stupid but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Can you copy paste the exact error messages?  which assembly could not be loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your IIS AppPool is set to x64.

Comment: A good idea but I already checked that.  Besides I don't think Sharepoint would run without it being set to x64.  The page is running on the visual studio dev server.  I'm not sure if the dev server has some way of being set to x64 though?

Answer (score 0):

The DLL's project build output / platform should be set to Any CPU.

[image]

Comment: OK so basically I figured out that the built in Cassini web server doesn't support x64....which is required by Sharepoint.  So the two essentially just aren't compatible from what I can tell.  Thank you for the responses.